# Why did Firefox, Mailspring, and other applications disappear from the dock in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: gnome-shell, 20.04, .desktop, ubuntu-dock, activities-overview

After upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04, I noticed upon reboot that Firefox, Mailspring, and several other apps are missing from both my Ubuntu dock and the Activities launcher. I can launch them by hand, but not using the <kbd>super</kbd>+search shortcut.

For example, I can confirm the Firefox .desktop shortcut exists:

```
dpkg -L firefox | grep .desktop
/usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop
```

And yet, when I hit the <kbd>super</kbd> button (for Activities) and type "firefox", I'm only greeted by the option to download it.

What gives?

Comment: I had noticed this with blender, I believe. An uninstall and reinstall of the application allowed it to be found again by search. I'm curious to read a better solution.